# Maybe class and optional parameters

Tags: c#, optional-parameters, option-type, compile-time-constant

I have an implementation of a Maybe / Option class in c#. Basic implementation is

```
public delegate Maybe<TOutput> Converter<in TInput, out TOutput>(TInput input);
public delegate TOutput ElseDelegate<out TOutput>();
public delegate Maybe<TOutput> ElseDelegate2<out TOutput>();

public interface Maybe<out TResult> : IEnumerable<TResult>
{
    Maybe<B> Bind<B>(Converter<TResult, B> f);
    TResult Value();
    bool IsSome();
}

public static class Maybe
{
    public static Maybe<T> None<T>()
    {
        return new None<T>();
    }
}

public interface INone<out TResult> : Maybe<TResult>
{
}

public interface ISome<out TResult> : Maybe<TResult>
{
}

public struct None<TResult> : INone<TResult>
{

    public IEnumerator<TResult> GetEnumerator()
    { yield break; }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    { yield break; }


    public bool IsSome() { return false; }

    public Maybe<TOutput> Bind<TOutput>(Converter<TResult, TOutput> f)
    {
        return new None<TOutput>();
    }

    public TResult Value()
    {
        throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("None has no value");
    }
}

public struct Some<TResult> : Maybe<TResult>
{
    private TResult _Value;
    public Some(TResult value)
    {
        _Value = value;
    }

    public IEnumerator<TResult> GetEnumerator()
    { yield return _Value; }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    { yield return _Value; }

    public bool IsSome() { return true; }

    public Maybe<TOutput> Bind<TOutput>(Converter<TResult, TOutput> f)
    {
        return f(_Value);
    }

    public TResult Value()
    {
        return this._Value;
    }
}
#endregion
```

with a bunch of extension methods I have not included here. This all works
fine. However a standard pattern I would like to implement is below,
using Maybe to implement optional parameter defaults as in F#

```
void DoSomeCalc
    ( Maybe<double> x = Maybe.None<double>()
    , Maybe<double> y = Maybe.None<double>()
    )
{
    this.X = x.Else( ()=> CalculateDefaultX() );
    this.Y = y.Else( ()=> CalculateDefaultY() );
}
```

so I can do

```
DoSomeCalc(x:10)
```

or

```
DoSomeCalc(y:20)
```

where Else provides a value if None is available. However
this is all nice in theory but C# optional parameters
must be compile time constants which completely screws
this pattern.

Can anybody suggest a fix that will keep the intent of
the pattern without introducing nullables or nulls here?

Is there anyway I can create a compile time constant to
represent None here that will work with my above 
implementation of Maybe?

Comment: Sounds like Dynamic to me...

Comment: Nothing to do with dynamic. Maybe is statically typed.

Comment: `params Maybe<double>[] args` maybe?

Comment: @Corak That defeats the whole purpose of names optional parameters

Comment: Why are you trying to reimplement `Nullable<T>`?

Comment: @svick: Because Nullable<T> can only be applied to value types, not classes. The Maybe pattern is needed to show that null is an expected value.

Comment: Hey, look a library for this! https://bitbucket.org/j2jensen/callmemaybe ^__^

Answer (score 7):

No, there's nothing you can do here. Your parameter type is a reference type, which means the only constant values available are `null` and string literals. (Obviously string literals aren't useful in your case; I only mention them as the *only* kind of non-null reference type constant.)

One option would be to make `Maybe<T>` a struct instead of an interface, with the default value the "none" value. This would then be basically the same as `Nullable<T>` but without the constraint that `T` had to be a non-nullable value type. You could then use:

```
void DoSomeCalc(Maybe<double> x = default(Maybe<double>),
                Maybe<double> y = default(Maybe<double>))
```

Sample code showing all of this:

```
using System;

struct Maybe<T>
{
    private readonly bool hasValue;
    public bool HasValue { get { return hasValue; } }

    private readonly T value;
    public T Value
    {
        get
        {
            if (!hasValue)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }
            return value;
        }
    }

    public Maybe(T value)
    {
        this.hasValue = true;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static implicit operator Maybe<T>(T value)
    {
        return new Maybe<T>(value);
    }
}

class Test
{
    static void DoSomeCalc(Maybe<double> x = default(Maybe<double>),
                           Maybe<double> y = default(Maybe<double>))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x.HasValue ? "x = " + x.Value : "No x");
        Console.WriteLine(y.HasValue ? "y = " + y.Value : "No y");
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("First call");
        DoSomeCalc(x: 10);

        Console.WriteLine("Second call");
        DoSomeCalc(y: 20);
    }
}
```

Obviously you'd want to add more functionality to `Maybe<T>`, such as overriding `ToString` and `Equals`, but you get the general idea. You can still have a non-generic `Maybe` class with factory methods too, of course.

Comment: Unfortunately Maybe<T> has to stay an interface to enable covariance on T. Damn c# Can only have covariance on interfaces. No implicit conversions to interfaces and now this compile time constant stuff. :(. However this post seems to claim the impossible. http://abdullin.com/journal/2009/10/6/zen-development-practices-c-maybe-monad.html scroll down to ``Reason 5: Initialization of Immutable classes``

Comment: @bradgonesurfing: Yup, that looks like it shouldn't compile. I don't have time to check the article right now, but is there a download link? I suspect the author just wrote code that he *expected* would work, but without trying it.

Comment: I couldn't see a download link but I'm guessing you are right and he didn't try it.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing: The fact that it was written in October 2009 and VS2010 didn't come out until April 2010 means that *at least* he didn't test it against a final release. I don't *think* there was a pre-release version of the C# 4 compiler which allowed non-compile-time-constant values for optional parameters but just *maybe* there was.

Comment: The correct answer for question of these heavy restrictions.

Comment: [Archive](http://archive.is/BuSUe) of the article in question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use null internally to mean Maybe.None<double>(). E.g.:

```
double DoSomeCalc
    ( Maybe<double> x = null
    , Maybe<double> y = null
    )
{
    x = x ?? Maybe.None<double>();
    y = y ?? Maybe.None<double>();
    this.X = x.Else( ()=> CalculateDefaultX() );
    this.Y = y.Else( ()=> CalculateDefaultY() );
}
```

It is not ideal as you have to document somewhere in comments that passing null means "use a particular default".

Comment: Defeats the purpose of using Maybe doesn't it? I can just use nullable in this case.

Comment: Depending on what's the purpose of Maybe. There is a difference between passing null and passing an instance of nullable with no value. nullable is a struct (value type) and so you really can't pass a null instead. C# compiler will convert the null into the proper constructor of nullable<T>. In your case you are passing a reference type (interface), which means passing null is actually valid and it's up to you to define what null Maybe<T> means. Your implementation of Maybe gives you more than the nullable type in C#.

Comment: Maybe.None means I don't want to pass anything. It has different semantics to actually passing null.

Comment: So what does passing null mean? Isn't it the same as "I don't want to pass anything"?

Comment: I want to differentiate between a caller actually not including a parameter in the call at compile time and accidentally passing in a null reference.

Comment: For example. DoSomeCalc(null, null) compiles the same as DoSomeCalc() and that is dangerous as the null could come from an incorrectly assigned variable way back in the code somewhere.

Comment: However I can't seem to get around the compiler limitiations and in this case I will just go for nullable doubles. :(

Comment: Unfortuantely C# won't allow default parameters for reference types other than null. So either you decide that null and Maybe.None<T> are the same thing in all cases or use structs. Depending on your needs you can define Maybe to be a struct and not an interface.

Comment: Unfortunately I need Maybe to be an interface to support covariance :(

Comment: @bradgonesurfing How can you be sure that `None` doesn't also come from an incorrectly assigned variable?

Comment: None would have to come from explicit assignment or cascade, not from an incorrect path. And the techniques for dealing with Maybe ensure you never get null reference exceptions. In f# it is almost impossible to get a null reference exception unless you are doing interop with c# or vb

Comment: Delphi solves the problem of passing `null` vs *"not passing anything"*. It comes up in the case of calling COM objects that were primarily meant to b called from scripting languages - where you can just not pass anything (and passing a `null` is invalid. Delphi has a special [`EmptyParam`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Variants.EmptyParam) object. When it sees that you passed  `EmptyParam` as a value, it knows you meant to have nothing there.